# resuming mget in shell

Tags: shell, ftp

i have a large set of files in host B and i'm trying to mget these files from the shell of host A (host A allows shell access while host B doesnt but gives ftp access).
In the middle of the job, the connection was lost and only half the number of files in host B were transferred to host A. I'm trying to resume mget without overwriting the already transferred files in host A but cant figure out how to do it. Any idea guys ?

PS: mreget is not available in host A's shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more generic approach would be to capture information about what is on B, confirm they all got to A or keep retying until you get them all.

something like

```
until ${allFilesTransfered:-false} ; do
    # get in file list of remote Files
ftp -in  > ${mgetTargets} <<-EOS
    open ${RemoteHost}
    $passwd
    cd $remoteDir
    ls ${fileSpec}*
    quit
    EOS

    # transport files with mget
    ftp -in <<-EOS
    open ${RemoteHost}
    $passwd
    prompt
    binary
    cd $remoteDir
    lcd $localDir
    mget $( cat mgetTargets )
    quit
    EOS

    # make a tmp file with files that are
    # now on your local machine
    cd $localDir
    ls -l > ${localDirOutput)

    # compare the 2 lists with diff,
    # if not diffs, then all files were copied
    diffOut="$(diff - ${localDirOutput} ${mgetTargets})"
case "${diffOut:-no_outputFound}" in
   no_outputFound ) allFilesTransfered=true ;;
esac
done
```

where mgetTargets and locaDirOutput would be defined to point to files.

I don't really have the resources or time to make this exact, but hopefully you get the idea.